# How to trigger a function without importing everything?

Tags: python

I programmed a gateway to a opcua-server with python-opcua.
The gateway is subscribing some values in the opcua. That is working good and fast.
Now I want to call a script that writes to the opcua. 
In principle, it works too. But because I have to import the whole gateway(and all opcua stuff), it is very slow...

My Question: Is is possible to trigger a function in my class-instance without imorting everything?

To start e.g. function setBool(), I have to import Gateway...

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5 -u
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import sys
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from threading import Thread

from opcua import Client
from opcua import ua

from subscribeOpcua import SubscribeOpcua
from cmdHandling import CmdHandling 
from keepConnected import KeepConnected

class Gateway(object):

    def __init__(self):

        OPCUA_IP   = '1.25.222.222'
        OPCUA_PORT = '4840' 
        OPCUA_URL = "opc.tcp://{}:{}".format(OPCUA_IP, str(OPCUA_PORT))
        addr = "OPCUA-URL:{}.".format(OPCUA_URL)

        # Setting up opcua-handler
        self.client = Client(OPCUA_URL)

        self.opcuaHandlers = [SubscribeOpcua()]

        # Connect to opcua
        self.connecter = KeepConnected(self.client,self.opcuaHandlers)
        self.connecter.start()

    def setBool(self, client):
        """Set e boolean variable on opcua-server.
        """
        path = ["0:Objects","2:DeviceSet"...]
        root = client.get_root_node()
        cmd2opcua = root.get_child(path)
        cmd2opcua.set_value(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """Open connecter when gateway is opened directly.
    """
    connect = Gateway()
```

Comment: You are importing a lot of unnecessary stuff. You can remove all imports except `Client`, `SubscribeOpcua`, `KeepConnected`.

Comment: Well, setBool only works on an instance of the class Gateway. Without importing Gateway, you cannot create an instance of the class, and therefore cannot call setBool on that instance. So in my opinion, it makes absolutely sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to prevent a code from runing when importing a module is to put it inside a method:

```
def import_first_part():
    global re
    global defaultdict
    print('import this first part')
    # import happen locally 
    # because when you do `import re` actually
    # re = __import__('re')
    import re
    from collections import defaultdict


def import_second_part():
    print('import pandas')
    # really unnecessary check here because if we import
    # pandas for the second time it will just retrieve the object of module
    # the code of module is executed only in the first import in life of application. 
    if 'pandas' in globals():
        return
    global pandas
    import pandas



def use_regex():
    import_first_part()
    # do something here



if __name__ == '__main__':
    use_regex()
    re.search('x', 'xb')  # works fine
```

I checked that `'pandas'` is in `global scope` before `reimport` it again but really this is not necessary, because when you import a module for the second time it's just **retrieved** no heavy calculation again.

Comment: @mkrieger Group the important statement in a separate method is unusual thing to do,  And I like to call this a trick you can call it whatever you want ^^. Don't be mad